# is it possible to install jmeter in M1 chip mac book pro

Tags: java, jmeter, apple-m1

Today when I install jmeter in my Macbook pro(macOS Monterey 12.5) with M1 pro chip like this:

```
brew install jmeter
```

shows error like this:

```
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
Warning: Unexpected method 'on_arm' called on Cask zulufx.
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
Warning: Unexpected method 'arch' called on Cask zulufx.
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs

Error: openjdk: undefined method `on_arm' for #<Resource:0x0000000137b0b020>
```

why did this happen? what should I do fix this problem? is it possible to install jmeter in Macbook Pro with M1 chip?

Comment: fyi it works on my M1 Max. Try brew update and brew doctor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like that you're trying to use [Azul JDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk) and one of its components:[zulufx](https://www.azul.com/blog/tag/zulufx/) hasn't been ported to [ARM yet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family)

So you can

1. Go here: https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk-aarch64/releases and choose the appropriate version (having `macos-aarch64.pkg` postfix), install it and ensure that `java` binary from this OpenJDK version is before any other Java versions
2. Go to [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and obtain the latest stable binary
3. Unpack JMeter tarball and launch `jmeter.sh` from its "bin" folder

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Code:**

```
arch -arm64 brew install jmeter
```

In my case this solved the issue.

Comment: sorry for my english